# Paypal Sandbox Testing Error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

i am in PAYPAL SANDBOX mode [as a developer] trying to integrate paypal into my client website. [Simple case of putting a BUY button onto the page - which I have done successfully] --- and then testing the payment process works].

Problem.......
When I test the BUY button it takes me to the SANDBOX payment page. From there I make a purchase [using my Eamil-buyer@gmail.com] account - set up by the Sandbox. The purchase goes through to PAY and from there i can make the payment which successfully registers in my Sandbox transactions log. However I have the following two problems on completing the purchase process---

1. I get the error 
   Rapids::Exception (N6Rapids5Tools13PimpExceptionE): Pimp RC: 3514
2. I am not being returned from the Pay Now page to my Thank You page --- on my website.

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure both the buyer and seller sandbox accounts you are using are showing as "Verified".

If not, verify them and see if the error goes away.

If so, try testing a checkout in Incognito mode (or equivalent with your browser.)  This will eliminate the use of any caching / cookies which can often cause conflicts with PayPal, especially on the sandbox.

Comment: Yes sadly they are both verified and i had already attempted icognito. So neither helped. It works fine when i dump Sandbox for the main site. I also tried switching off PDN and that didnt work either..